# How to efficiently add an array as WPF DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, string, datagrid

My application receives an 16 byte array (actually an array of strings representing bytes) that I need to display in a WPF DataGrid: one byte per column, 16 bytes per row. I would like to create the columns and add the byte array to a new row without having to repeat code 16 times in every new record.

My current (and repetitive) approach looks like:

Creating the 16 columns:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    HexadecimalGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Binding = new Binding("b" + i.ToString()),
    });
}
```

The received array:

```
string[] theData = new string[16] { "1A", "2C", "05", "11", "D2" ... "F9" };
```

Adding a new row to the DataGrid:

```
HexadecimalGrid.Items.Add(new {b0 = theData[0], b1 = theData[1] ... b15 = theData[15]});
```

So, is there a better way to do it? instead of typing `bx = theData[x]` 16 times?

Comment: why you cannot use binding in XAML ?

Comment: I could, like binding it to a class for example. The problem is that i will need to declare 16 (useless) fields in an class to render it as an entire row. I just need to *display* the data so I think it will be a little bit overwhelming. If you know any other approach using binding (that doesn't include this level of repetition) I would be really glad to know more about!

Comment: @KawaungaXDG Then use a data table as the source of the grid and populate the data rows as needed in loops.

Comment: You could perhaps provide the array through a bindable property, and then establish for each column a binding to an array element like (example in XAML form) `{Binding ArrayProperty[1]}`. Of course, when you create those bindings for each column programmatically, you place the correct array index in the term for the binding source...

Comment: @Nkosi, that's a pretty good ideia, I'll definitely give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @elgonzo Nice ideia, I'll give it a try too. Although my skills on WPF binding are not a state of the art :)

Comment: There are side effects to binding using an index. I'd translate the array to a viewmodel rowvm. Bind the itemssource to a public property observablecollection<rowvm>. That goes in a viewmodel which is the datacontext of the window. You read data in, translate into viewmodels. Edit. Translate back to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree that there are better ways to do this, but to answer your question: you can do this with LINQ using an aggregate to build an ExpandoObject:

```
var newItem = Enumerable.Range(0, theData.Length)
    .Aggregate<int, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(
        new ExpandoObject(),
        (collection, index) =>
        {
            collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>($"b{index}", theData[index]));
            return collection;
        },
        collection => collection);
```

UPDATE: actually it's a bit more readable if you use its IDictionary interface:

```
var newItem = Enumerable.Range(0, theData.Length)
    .Aggregate<int, IDictionary<string, object>, IDictionary<string, object>>(
        new ExpandoObject(),
        (dict, index) =>
        {
            dict.Add($"b{index}", theData[index]);
            return dict;
        },
        dict => dict);
```

Or you could just use a loop. :)